# Usar ciclo while combinado con excepcion error en python

Tags: python

He intentado hacer un programa para que siempre le repita al usuario que introduzca el valor requerido para funcionar pero no logro que el bucle funcione, solo quiero que siempre se repita el bucle para visualizar el error, este es un ejemplo de mi código

```py
try:
    c = int(input("Ingresa un valor:"))
    while c != int:
        try:
            c/0
        except ValueError:
            print ("prueba")
            c = int(input("Ingresa un valor:"))
except ValueError:
    print("No puede dividir una cadena de caracteres con un número")
    c = int(input("Ingresa un valor:"))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("No puedes dividir entre cero")
```

Comment: Usa 3 de ` para abrir y cerrar tu codigo, como lo tienes no se entiende nada

Comment: @AlfaRojo recuerda que puedes editar la publicación y otros la revisarán :D

Comment: @Christian Fijate que sii lo intenté, pero me dijo que necesita 10 cambios mínimos

Comment: @AlfaRojo poner 3 ` arriba y 3 ` abajo (son 6) y colocar el nombre del lenguaje (python ya son otros 6) en tottal 12 cambios :D

Answer (score 0):

Voy a contestar la pregunta solo porque vi que hacias `while c!=int` no me quiero imaginar que piensas que hace eso y voy a ayudarte en tu problema.

Lo que tu quieres es validar que lo que se ingrese sea un número mayor que 0, para esto solo debemos de cambiar el orden de los `try/except` y `while`. Pero antes vamos a explicar el error que cometes.

Al hacer `while c!=int` estas comparando una varaible con un tipo de dato, si bien la variable puede contener cualquier cosa, dentro d tu código solo se limita a tener un valor numérico. Si tu quieres saber si un dato/variable es un número entero entonces debes de comparar el tipo de objeto y para eso se usa la metaclase `type`, lo correcto hubiera sido hacer `while type(c)==int` donde se compara el tipo de objeto que contiene la variable `c` con la clase `int`. Sin embargo esto no tiene mucho sentido por la línea anterior `c = int(input("Ingresa un valor:"))` por lo que tu ciclo siempre será `True` al menos que se ingrese un caracter no numerico y en ese caso saltaría la excepción.

Luego en caso salte la excepción se ejecuta el bloque del código de la excepción y en ninguno de esos hay un `while` (y tampoco lo necesitas) para que se siga ejecutando el código, por esta razón el `try/except` debe estar dentro del `while`

```py
while True:
    try:
        c = int(input("Ingresa un valor:"))
        #haces algo más
        #para terminar el ciclo poner un 
        #break
    except ValueError:
        print("No puede dividir una cadena de caracteres con un número")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("No puedes dividir entre cero")
```

También puedes olvidarte de los `try/except` y usar `if/else` :D

Comment: Pasa que básicamente es una practica lo que estoy realizando para manejar las excepciones, entonces quiero es hacer un bucle while donde si el usuario coloca un string entrara al bucle hasta que coloque un numero, donde después me dará otra excepción y allí acabara el programa, se que no tiene mucho sentido lo que quiero hacer pero lo quiero hacer por practicar. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Voy a intentar hacerlo a tu manera

Comment: no es necesario que lo hagas a mi manera, puedes hacerlo a tu manera pero teniendo en cuenta lo que te dije y guiandote de mi código. La  mejor manera  de aprender  es experimentando :D

Comment: Muchas gracias en serio :) De la manera en me has mostrado me ha funcionado perfecto para practicar.